# what property should i set to Fit the text in label

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, label, nokia

I want to display a big string in a `Qlablel` for this I simply have created a label in the Qt GUI editor.

Then set the string with the `Wordwrap` property to "ON".

Here text is not coming to the next line itself. Instead, it's crossing the view region.

However, if I give an `"\n"` it works well.

How do I put up the big string in a label to display in a visible region?

Answer (score 1):

```
label->setWordWrap(true);
```

See [the QLabel::setWordWrap(bool on) documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qlabel.html#wordWrap-prop).